import bootstrap show me issus ' Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default '
i install bootstrap in my project and when i try to import it show me this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default

the code for my main.mts:

import  bootstrap  from "bootstrap"

const modalInstance = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(modal) as bootstrap.Modal;


when i try to use cdn its work ....
package.json file:
{
  "name": "typescript-social-media-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.10",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3"
  }
}



tsconfig.ts file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}



so why this happend and how to slove the error ??

Show package.json, tsconfig.json. Try with require.
